# Is there any way to get the default ResourceProviderFactory of an asp.net app?

Tags: asp.net, localization, resourceproviderfactory

I've succesfully implemented a custom localization provider for my asp.net application. I'm working now in a fall-back scenario where for some reason there's no way of creating the CustomResourceProviderFactory or if I don't want to use it in specific scenario I want to be able to use the default ProviderFactory in asp.net

Is there any way to create or get the instance of that class? I'm not able to figure out what the exact type is either, all info that I find is regarding creating a custom factory which I've already completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me

```
var _resxResourceProviderFactoryType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ResourceProviderFactory)).GetType("System.Web.Compilation.ResXResourceProviderFactory");                                                             
var _resourceProviderFactory = (ResourceProviderFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(_resxResourceProviderFactoryType);
```